# URL Restriction using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

If i copy the URL of welcome page after login and paste the URL of welcome page after logout it is redirect to login page it is working fine as i am checking with local storage name. Now the problem is I am not able to go to register page as it should be opened while user logged out for new user registration because the user will be null in local storage, Please anyone help me how to solve this problem.

This is the route for my application

```
app.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'app/components/login/login.html',
        controller : 'loginCtrl'

    }).when('/register/', {
        templateUrl : 'app/components/register/register.html',
        controller : 'registerController'
    }).when('/welcome/', {
        templateUrl : 'app/components/dashBoard/dashboard.html',
        controller : 'welcomeController'
    }).when('/logout', {
        templateUrl : 'app/components/login/login.html',
        controller : 'LogoutController'
    }).when('/forgotPwd', {
        templateUrl : 'app/components/forgotPassword/forgotPassword.html',
        controller : 'forgotPwdController'
    }).when('/changePwd', {
        templateUrl : 'app/components/changePwd/changePassword.html',
        controller : 'changePwdController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : "/"
    });
} ]).run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(next) {
        $rootScope.username = localStorage.getItem("UserName");
        //alert("redirecting to login");
      if ($rootScope.username === null) {
        // no logged user, redirect to /login
        if ( next.templateUrl === "app/components/login/login.html") {
        } else {
          $location.path("/");
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: this pattern is very fragile and error prone.  You *can* solve the problem you are encountering now by checking `next.templateUrl` against more than one template, but the more pages you have that require anonymous access, the more complex that logic will become.  You should consider rethinking this method of security.

Comment: Hi @Claies any idea for this

Comment: There are plenty of examples of good ways to implement this logic;  First, don't check against `next.templateUrl`; that introduces a case where changing your template file name breaks your authentication (very difficult to troubleshoot).  If you **must** use `$routeChangeStart`, you might try adding a new boolean property in the route, like `allowAnonymous` or something similar.  However, I would still avoid this pattern if possible.

Comment: @Sudhir, So, do you want to go to register page when user enter the url for the register page in a new tab or window?

Comment: @AbhilashPA no after logout i will be redirected to login page and the localstorage will be cleared, Now i want to open a register page in same window link is provided in login page itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(next) {
        $rootScope.username = localStorage.getItem("UserName");
        //alert("redirecting to login");
      if ($rootScope.username == null) {
        // no logged user, redirect to /login
        if ( $location.$$url == "/" || $location.$$url == "/register/") {
                // do nothing. Do not redirect
        } else {
          // redirect to default path
          $location.path("/");
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: this is indeed the solution I was suggesting, but I highly recommend avoiding this, for the reasons I stated in my comments above.